# typeahead.min.js Github link not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, github, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I implemented a search bar dropdown using bootstrap v3.0.0 and typeahead.js. At the time of completion of my project(2 months ago). I used the following to include the template engine and typeahead.min.js

```
<link href="http://raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<script src="http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/hogan-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Now all of a sudden I'm welcomed with a "There isn't a GitHub Page here." when I tried to access

```
http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/js/hogan-2.0.0.js
```

My search dropdown isn't working anymore. I tried to replace the hogan template link with a working link `https://raw.github.com/twitter/hogan.js/master/web/builds/2.0.0/hogan-2.0.0.js`
but there are no alternatives for typeahead.min.js [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/releases). Infact there is not typeahead.min.js in any version. Now they have changed it to

```
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js
```

which doesn't work since it is upgraded version. Any idea how I can find which version   I'm using. I'm really confused with what is happening and need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [cdnjs.com](http://www.cdnjs.com) or [jsdelivr.com](http://www.jsdelivr.com). They both have hogan and typeahead hosted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for sourcing your Javascript dependencies.

For example if you used [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/), instead of:

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js">
```

you would use:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you're always using the latest master branch, Github broke the emedding of javascript hosted at raw.github.com. However, it's a simple fix, simply remove the  "." period to use the domain: "rawgithub.com"

original:

```
<link href="http://raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

becomes:

```
<link href="http://rawgithub.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```